# Worst case time complexities - lower bounds, vs upper bounds, vs tightbounds

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Wouldn't it make sense for the worst case time complexity to be a tight bound, as there can only be one worst case time complexity?

So if I was asked to find a lower bound for an algorithm's worst case time complexity, wouldn't it be the same as simply it's worst case time complexity (if I were to describe the bound and make it as tight as possible) . I would be interested in hearing your thoughts and opinions.

From another post:

The way you describe it, pick any quadratic sort algorithm, say bubble sort:

Worst case upper bound can be said to be O(n^3).

Worst case lower bound can be said to be Ω(n^2).

The best case running time can be said to be Θ(n), when the input is already sorted and you check this with a single pass before starting the algorithm, or use optimizations that terminate the algorithm prematurely in this case.

Comment: What do you mean by - "one worst case time complexity?"

Comment: I would assume the worst case time complexity would be the absolute worst case time complexity. If you had two worse case time complexities, that's not possible because unless they were 'equal' in their worseness, wouldn't one have to be worse than the other?

Comment: By definition of `O` (|f(n)| <= c*g(n)), it's true for `n` - `O(n^2)` & `O(n^3)`. But I see what you're saying.